# Random Token Generation with game launcher and SQL database

Tags: php, sql, database, token

Okay so my problem is, with this php script, a random token is generated and used to log into the game with your account, but sometimes, you may get the same token as another account and log into theirs instead. What I need is not to completely change my script, but to slightly modify it so that it can not produce the same token twice.

```
<?php

                   ////////////DATABASE CREDENTIALS///////////
                         $generateToken = generateToken();    
                         $host = "********\SQLExpress";  
                         $user = "********";                        
                         $password = "*******";            
                         $database = "**********";

                   //////////////////////////////////////////

          //////////////////////Database Connection//////////////////////////// 
          $connect = mssql_connect($host,$user,$password);                    
          $db = mssql_select_db($database,$connect);                          
          if(!$db) die('<center>Connection with SQL Server failed!</center>');
          $succes = 0;                                         
          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


         /////////////////// Sanitize Data ////////////////////////
               function sanitize($data) {
               $data = trim($data);
               $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
               return $data;
               }

      //////////////////////////////// Generate Token /////////////////////////////////
      function generateToken($length = 50) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $randomToken = '';
               for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                 $randomToken .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
                   }
                    return $randomToken;
                      }
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



               ///////////////// Define Username & Password ///////////////////
                   $username = sanitize($_POST['username']);
                   $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);
               ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



          //////////////////// Check if Username & Password are correct //////////////////
                      $select_account = mssql_query("Select * from dbo.tAccounts where sUsername='$username' and sUserPass='$password'");
                      $verify_account = mssql_num_rows($select_account);
                         while($row = mssql_fetch_array($select_account))
                            {
                             $nemid = $row['nEMID'];
                            }
          ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


         //////////////////////// Error Handling /////////////////////////////
                          if($verify_account == 0) {
                          echo 'error';
                          $succes = 0; } else { $succes = 1;
         /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


       ////////////////////////// Token Verification //////////////////////////////                   
       $getnemid = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM dbo.tTokens WHERE nEMID ='$nemid'");
       $tokenCheck = mssql_num_rows($getnemid);
       if($tokenCheck != 0) {
       $succes = 1;
       $inserttoken = mssql_query("UPDATE dbo.tTokens SET sToken='$generateToken' WHERE nEMID = '$nemid'");
       } else {
       $succes = 1;
       $createtoken = mssql_query("INSERT INTO dbo.tTokens (nEMID,sToken) VALUES ('$nemid','$generateToken')"); 
       } }
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



       /////////////////////////// Connect to Client /////////////////////////////////
          if($succes != 0) {
          $GetClientDATA = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM dbo.tTokens WHERE nEMID = '$nemid'");
          while($getToken = mssql_fetch_array( $GetClientDATA )) { 
          echo $getToken['sToken']; } } 
       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a unique ID (function.uniqid -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)? Chances of collision are negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the current UNIX time in there. UNIX time is a timestamp in seconds that started counting up in 1970 1 January 1970, so it will never get the same value again.

In php you can get the unix timestamp easily using:

```
strtotime("now")
```

You can then put that somewhere in your randomly generated token. If you need it more 'secure' you could also split the timestamp at a random position and then put the two parts apart of eachother.

Comment: what if two tokens are generated at the same time? A second-based resolution is even more likely to generate a collision here.

Comment: There is still the random part, which should prevent same tokens

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
microtime();
```

It gives the current unix time down to a millisecond.
If you are still not satisfied, just check if that token exists and if yes generate a new one.
Or simply use the solution by Christian Kiewiet. :)

Comment: You could also add in the current user IP and generate a SHA Hash out of it. If that generates a collision i dont know what wouldnt.